# Edit different shader node tree at same time

Tags: node-editor, shaders

When using the shader node editor, I would like to be able to view and edit different materials at the same time.  However, even if I split my view into two sections, both set to view the shader node editor, the views are synchronized. So if I'm initially editing Material 1 in both node editors, I'd like to set the second node editor to Material 2.  But when I do that, both editors change to Material 2.

The best I can do is enter a node group in one editor while the other remains at the top level node group.

How do I edit two materials simultaneously?

Comment: One way is using two instances of Blender.

Comment: Hello :). There's a *pin* icon next to the material name. Just pin the material and open a different one in another editor.

Comment: @JachymMichal and Gorgious both suggested the same solution.  Thank you!